# @import not working in application.scss on Ruby application

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I have a RoR application that is working fine. I embedded an another one in to that one (Thredded). Everything is working fine, except that this other application does not apply css style...

my  ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss file look like this:

```
 @import "thredded";
 @import "font-awesome";
```

and my stylesheet directory look like this:

```
./app/assets/stylesheets
├── application.scss
├── ckeditor
├── errors.scss
├── fonts
├── foundation_and_overrides.scss
├── scaffolds.scss
├── thredded
└── v1
```

The Thredded directory (the application I am trying to embedded):

```
./app/assets/stylesheets/thredded
├── base
├── _base.scss
├── components
├── _dependencies.scss
├── _email.scss
├── layout
├── _thredded.scss
└── utilities
```

I am probably doing something wrong, but I am not really into RoR, and I can't understand what...

Answer (score 0):

RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Solve the issue ! thanks